# What is the syntax to use Map.thy

Tags: isabelle

So far I can define a map

```
map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4::int)]
```

of type

```
'a => int option
```

When I try to get the domain of the map:

```
dom (map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4::int)])
```

give the error

```
Wellsortedness error:
Type 'b not of sort enum
Cannot derive subsort relation {equal,numeral} < enum
```

The examples in Enum.thy only show finite cases, how do you prove the enum property for an infinite type like int or nat?

**Update 1:**
Fixed the syntax and give the exact error message

Comment: Do you mean `dom (map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4)])`? If so, it seems you need to learn more about the syntax of HOL in general, as this is not yet `Map`-specific.

Comment: Yes, `dom (map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4)])` but still get an error. Which article or book would you recommend to learn about HOL syntax?

Comment: The tutorials on http://isabelle.in.tum.de/documentation.html, I guess.

Comment: I recommend [Programming and Proving](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2016/doc/prog-prove.pdf). The literal "tutorial" is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem that occurs when trying to evaluate the expression

```
dom (map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4::int)])
```

e.g. using the "value" command.

The reason why this doesn't work is that "map_of" essentially gives you a function and the domain of a function is not in general computable.

Still, you can use your map and carry out proofs:

```
lemma "dom (map_of [(1, 2), (3, 4::nat)]) = {1, 3}"
by simp
```

Or, if you'd rather have something computable, then you can just keep using lists of tuples. In Isabelle2016-1, there will be a dedicated "finite map" type too:

```
theory Scratch
  imports "~~/src/HOL/Library/Finite_Map"
begin

value "fmdom' (fmap_of_list [(1, 2), (3, 4::nat)])"
(* prints "{1, 1 + 1 + 1}" *)
```