# Maps with finite domain

Tags: dictionary, isabelle

I need a finite map in a datatype. I went with the typical (partial) map until I hit a road block in a proof, which can only be fixed by introducing a `finite (dom m)` predicate. Carrying this fact around is tedious, so is there some solution in the standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40186031/388010) (from which I also stole the following example), there is a finite map type `fmap` in `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Finite_Map"` since `Isabelle2016-1`.

```
theory Scratch
  imports "~~/src/HOL/Library/Finite_Map"
begin

value "fmdom' (fmap_of_list [(1, 2), (3, 4::nat)])"
(* prints "{1, 1 + 1 + 1}" *)
```

Comment: I literally googled for this 5 times before hitting the cited answer. The top results are from a mailing list thread from 2006, so I figured to make this more amenable to SEO.